# Is there any reason for expression like !Boolean.FALSE.equals()?

Tags: java, spring

When browsing the Spring's source code, I encountered code like `if (!Boolean.FALSE.equals(pv.conversionNecessary)) {...}`

After some research, I also found codes like `!Boolean.FALSE.equals` and `!Boolean.TRUE.equals` exist in other open-source projects too.

I wonder what's the possible reasons for not using the apparently **concise** expression?

Comment: I think this goes back to very old Java, before auto boxing/unboxing conversions from Boolean objects to boolean primitives.

Answer (score 3):

There are various reasons why this kind of thing might be necessary.

In this example, `pv` is an instance of `PropertyValue` which declares the `conversionNecessary` as follows:

```
/** Package-visible field that indicates whether conversion is necessary. */
@Nullable
volatile Boolean conversionNecessary;
```

([source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/PropertyValue.java))

From this, we can infer that it is not unexpected for `conversionNecessary` to be `null`.

So ... the verbose form `if (!Boolean.FALSE.equals(pv.conversionNecessary)) {...}` is dealing with the `null` case.  `Boolean.FALSE.equals(null)` is `false`.

By contrast, the more concise form `if (!pv.conversionNecessary) {...}` would throw an NPE.

It is also worth noting that since `conversionNecessary` is `volatile` here, an alternative version that did an explicit `null` check would need to use a temporary variable to avoid race conditions; e.g.

```
Boolean necessary = pv.conversionNecessary;
if (necessary == null || necessary) { ... }
```

---

Another scenario where you might do this kind of thing is if the declared type of the variable is `Object` rather than `Boolean`.